# How to convert json format

Tags: ios

How to remove `\` and `\n`. This two is characters is coming.

```
   {
        PageNumber = 1;
        businessCode = "{\n  \"businessCode\" : \"[]\"\n}";
        businessName = "";
        categoryKeyword = "Ladies Traditional Wear Pagenumber";
        languageCode = en;
        location = "";
        paginationSize = 5;
    }
```

Comment: How are you generating this string?  Is it the output from NSLog or similar?  These are new line characters and escape characters  which will be ignored by the JSON parser

Comment: I think you showed wrong response.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: I have used for this lines  NSMutableDictionary *contentDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [contentDictionary setValue:@"[]" forKey:@"businessCode"];
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contentDi
    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Could you explain question in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

May be below answer is helpful for you.Follow this

```
//just give your URL instead of my URL
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"Your URL"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;

NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

//You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

//After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

From above code,you can get the correct format of JSON.Try this one.

Answer (score -1):

`NSMutableCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [NSMutableCharacterSet new];
    [charactersToRemove addCharactersInString:@"\n"];
    [charactersToRemove addCharactersInString:@"\\"]; //This respresent obly one backslash, In Objective-c you have to support it with another slash
    [jsonString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove];`